# Can Avahi zeroconf mDNS correctly resolve bare hostnames?

Tags: avahi

Ubuntu supports resolving MACHINE.local names. How can you configure it correctly to resolve only MACHINE as the hostname? By default it appears to assume that this is a DNS search.

Comment: I don't think its possible on local-lan. `avahi-daemon` is programmed in such a way that other machine in same network can be reached using `$HOSTNAME.local`

Comment: I don't know if this works, but supposedly installing netBIOS (or Samba) will let you use bare names from Windows.